# How do I use MySQL Binlog for PITR

Tags: mysql, recovery, pitr

I am attempting to recover lost data using mysqlbinlog. Admittedly I am far from an expert in using MySQL, and even farther when using command line, so any advise would be very very welcome. I've seen so many docs that say what to do to view the binlogs, but it does not work at all on my machine. What am I doing wrong here?

[This is exactly what happens every time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hJM2.png)

I've tried running this multiple times. I've also tried listing out the path to the binlog file in that Data folder.

[Update: Same thing happens when using MySQL Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HXj4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the `mysqlbinlog` command at a shell prompt, not in the MySQL client.

Comment: Just did that, with the same result. Running MySQLServer 8.0.26 on a windows machine and it just won't do anything with the mysqlbinlog

Comment: Your screenshot clearly shows that you're trying to run the command in the MySQL client. If you got the same result, then you're still trying to run the command in that client. You need to open a command window.

Comment: I've used MySQL command line client, MySQL Shell, and the Windows Command Line with the same result on all 3.

Comment: Well, I've now realized how dense I was being thanks to a nice long break. Finally got mysqlbinlog to work, now to try and use it. Thank you Bill for your help, even though I wasn't able to grasp what you were telling me right away haha.